# VLC mosaic stops after 10 seconds

Tags: video, vlc, mosaic

I am trying to merge my videos into mosaic, but i've encountered a problem. Video stops after 10 seconds and returns into interface (I am using --no-video-deco)

What did I tried:

- Change of files (other format, lower resolutions, different videos per channel)
- Freeing more RAM (did not changed anything)
- VLC update (2.1.5 -> 2.2.1)
- --live-caching=/*300-5000*/
- starting videos from SSD drive

My shortcut

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --vlm-conf "C:\mosaic.conf" --mosaic-width=1920 --mosaic-height=1080 --mosaic-keep-picture --mosaic-rows=2 --mosaic-cols=2 --mosaic-position=1 --mosaic-order=1,2,3,4
```

mosaic.conf

```
new channel1 broadcast enabled                                                       
setup channel1 input C:\Users\Aramil\Videos\film.mkv
setup channel1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1,height=540}}

new channel2 broadcast enabled                                                       
setup channel2 input C:\Users\Aramil\Videos\film.mkv
setup channel2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=2,height=540}}

new channel3 broadcast enabled                                                       
setup channel3 input C:\Users\Aramil\Videos\film.mkv
setup channel3 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=3,height=540}}

new channel4 broadcast enabled                                                       
setup channel4 input C:\Users\Aramil\Videos\film.mkv
setup channel4 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=4,height=540}}

new mosaic broadcast enabled
setup mosaic input C:\Users\Aramil\Pictures\TwoWorldsOneSun_Bouic_2683.jpg
setup mosaic output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mp4v,VB=20000,acodec=none,fps=24,scale=1}:display

control mosaic play
control channel1 play
control channel2 play
control channel3 play
control channel4 play
```

debug messages

```
(...)
avcodec warning: almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (256245344667)
stream_out_transcode debug: drift is too high (116666, resetting master sync
main warning: original picture size is undefined
main warning: original picture size is undefined
(...)
avcodec warning: almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (256245744667)
stream_out_transcode debug: drift is too high (116666, resetting master sync
main warning: original picture size is undefined
main debug: EOF reached
main warning: original picture size is undefined
avcodec warning: almost fed libavcodec with two frames with the same PTS (256245944667)
main debug: removing module "rawvideo"
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `J444', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: removing a sout input (sout_input:06ae8d70)
main debug: removing module "rawvideo"
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
main debug: Filter 0d318f4c removed from chain
main debug: removing module "swscale"
main debug: removing module "avcodec"
avcodec debug: ffmpeg codec (MPEG-4 Video) stopped
main debug: killing decoder fourcc `mp4v', 0 PES in FIFO
main debug: saving a free vout
main debug: reusing provided vout
main debug: removing module "image"
main debug: removing module "record"
main debug: removing module "filesystem"
main debug: Program doesn't contain anymore ES
main error: Failed to resize display
main debug: destroying useless sout
main debug: destroying chain... (name=transcode)
main debug: removing module "stream_out_transcode"
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: removing module "yuvp"
main debug: removing module "swscale"
main debug: Filter 0d315ff4 removed from chain
main debug: removing module "mosaic"
main debug: removing module "blend"
main debug: destroying chain done
main debug: destroying chain... (name=display)
main debug: removing module "stream_out_display"
main debug: destroying useless vout
main debug: removing module "direct3d"
direct3d debug: Direct3D scene released successfully
direct3d debug: DirectXEventThread terminating
direct3d debug: DirectXCloseWindow
direct3d debug: WinProc WM_DESTROY
main debug: removing module "freetype"
main debug: removing module "yuvp"
main debug: removing module "swscale"
main debug: destroying chain done
main warning: can't get output picture
avcodec warning: disabling direct rendering
swscale warning: can't get output picture
stream_out_mosaic_bridge error: image conversion failed
(...)
main warning: can't get output picture
avcodec warning: disabling direct rendering
swscale warning: can't get output picture
stream_out_mosaic_bridge error: image conversion failed
(...)
```

And an additional question: while playing mosaic videos do not fill full screen. I get 65px free space on the right. Videos are 1920x1080, my desktop resolution is the same alike with mosaic dimensions. What is wrong?

My system:

```
Win 8.1 64-bit
i7-4710HQ
8GB RAM
Intel HD Graphics 4600 + NVidia GTX 850M
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I believe the problem is that VLC will only 'play' an image for 10 seconds by default.  You can tell VLC to play forever by adding `--image-duration=-1` to your command line.

See the [VLC Mosaic](https://wiki.videolan.org/Mosaic/) page, which uses this in Step 2 for testing.